# How to parse date string in format yyyy mm dd :hh mm ss to yyyy mm dd , in Vuejs ,with momentjs says its deprecated

Tags: date, datetime, vuejs2, momentjs, date-format

Tried parsing date coming as response  `yyyy mm dd :hh mm ss` to `yyyy mm dd`  from rest api that i am mapping in data table as one of the header, 
    below is that i am trying ,

```
{
  name: "Created Date",
  key: "creationDate" | moment('YYYY-MM-DD'),
  sortable: true,
},
```

Below is the error:

```
moment.js?c1df:283 Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release.     
Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
    Arguments: 
    [0] _isAMo
```

Comment: if you're just removing the time part, split the date string before giving it to moment

Comment: Could you share the whole component? Not sure how exactly you're trying to inject `moment` here.

Comment: m injecting it like ds const moment = require('moment'); @raina77ow

Comment: try passing the date to the moment constructor, something like moment(your_date,'YYYY-MM-DD');

Comment: @vjr12 tried doing ds ,  {
            name: "Created Date",
            key: "creationDate ? moment(creationDate,'DD-MMM-YYYY':''",
            sortable: true,
          }, doesnt work

Comment: @PujaEce No, I mean the whole component. It seems that you're trying to pipe a result of function, and not a function itself; I wonder what's the context of using this pipe here.

Comment: just see again the date structure coming in response. how is it coming ?